# com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml

Tags: android, gradle, jackson, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I am creating one app that uses a RestAPI to fetch data, and for that operation I am using retrofit 2, okhttp3 and jackson for parsing json to object, my app also use Firebase Cloud Messaging

when I compile my code it gives me following error & I can't able to run it

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml
>       File1: /Users/silent/work/silentinfotech/DoorEye/app/libs/jackson-databind-2.7.2.jar
>       File2: /Users/silent/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar

I am using **Android Studio 2.1.1** and  **OS X El Capitan 10.11.2**

some Library added in projects libs folder

[converter-jackson-2.0.2.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-jackson/2.0.2)

[jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.7.0)

[jackson-core-2.7.2.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.7.2)

[jackson-databind-2.7.2.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.7.2)

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.silentinfotech.dooreye"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   // compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
   // compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also tried adding following in my build.gradle file but it don't work for me

```
packagingOptions {              
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'         
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'          
}
```

also tried invalidate caches & restart, and also rebuild, clean, even I tried with manually deleting caches but still its give me error

I am using firebase Cloud  messaging in my project when I remove all the dependency of Firebase Cloud Messaging  then project successfully run but when I add FCM dependency it always give error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of this

```
packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
```

try this

```
 packagingOptions {

   exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
   exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
   exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
   exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

   }
```

and more thing

Remove this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

from Bottom and add to Top after this `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### Update :

just remove

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

and apply dependencies.

Comment: Error changed to     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AbstractTypeResolver.class

Comment: you suggest me to remove it but i required all those libs , i am using it on my app

Comment: @IndrajitSinhRayjada remove this line and add dependencies sorry i write short thing.

Comment: yeh works like charm , thank you @ironman u mad my day :) , i accepted ans

Answer (score 2):

Make changes in the gredle, You have to `exclude` to maven too.

```
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven

}
```

and if you are using `google-play-service` you can exclude the `annotation`
like

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
}
```

Or you can try this also

```
configurations {
all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Error changed to Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotation.class

Comment: Thank you for your help , accepted ans. work like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

add this
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'