# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, compiler-errors, libraries

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.xml
  >   File1: D:\STUDIO\Mobility_Android\FFS\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\FFS\ShowCaseViewLibrary\unspecified\jars\classes.jar
  >   File2: D:\STUDIO\Mobility_Android\FFS\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\FFS\AndroidBetterPickers\unspecified\jars\classes.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

add this in your build.gradle file

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.xml' 
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: By Adding these lines solved my problem..                                               android {
    packagingOptions {

        exclude  'META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.xml'
        exclude  'META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.properties'

    }   got this from the below url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428636/com-android-builder-packaging-duplicatefileexception-duplicate-files-copied-in?rq=1

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer. Accept it if it helped. Thank You