# How to fix this error when I run project firebase phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I use this dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
Error:
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\Usman.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
>       File2: D:\eRozgaar\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\11.4.2\jars\classes.jar

my build.gradil is :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usman.erozgaar"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  
        'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
packagingOptions
        {

    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

      }

    }

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
//    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
//    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'

}
```

Comment: Can I see your build.gradle?

Comment: @ Giovanni Terlingen check my build.gradle

Comment: Check my answer, did you exclude the maven folder as well?

Comment: yes  but it shows still same error.

Comment: Read my answer. Your dependencies are below the packagingOptions, they need to be on top!

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954063/5457878

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following line to the bottom in your app's `build.gradle`, inside the `android {}` and below your `dependencies {}`.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven'
}
```

This will remove unnecessary files during your build, which should prevent your duplicate file exception which is caused by merging your dependencies.

See: [com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428636/com-android-builder-packaging-duplicatefileexception-duplicate-files-copied-in)

Answer (score 0):

Solution of my problem was

```
packagingOptions 
{
exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-
core/pom.properties'
exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/pom.xml'
}
```

duplicate file link copy from error message and past in

```
packagingOptions 
{ 
 exclude 'past here copied file link'
}
```