# Released apk is not able to login

Tags: android, json, google-play-services

I'm not able to login to released apk but debug apk is working fine. google_services.json file is missing to released apk i'm not getting why its happening like this. please some one help me to solve this. Below i listed my app-level dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile files('libs/opencsv-2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services_lib.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project-level dependencies

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'
}
```

i'm getting this error
`E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE`

please anybody help me out.

Comment: can you please share log??

Comment: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

Comment: once see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428636/com-android-builder-packaging-duplicatefileexception-duplicate-files-copied-in

Comment: if i add packagingOptions it start giving me wrongings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the SHA-1 of release build from the Cloud Console.

- Open https://console.cloud.google.com/
- Select your application from the Drop Down at the top
- APIs and Services -> Credentials
- Add a key with SHA-1 for the release as well. (You might already having debug key registered)

Update: Add signing config to your app's `build.gradle` file and run `singingReport` from the gradle task.

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release-key.keystore")
            storePassword 'passwotd'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
...
```

Now, click on the "Gradle" button in the Android studio on the right side panel. 
Click "project name" -> ":app" -> "Tasks" -> "android" -> Double click "signingReport"

After it completes, click on the "Gradle Console" at the bottom right corner. It will show all the SHA-1 for all the keys.

Find the release build key's SHA-1.

Hope it helps

Comment: how find release apk sha-1 key? is it same as debug sha-1 key?

Comment: No it's not. Have you added release signing config in build gradle ?

Comment: Great to hear that! :)